# Word used to describe a connection problem during a call

Tags: vocabulary

I'm a watching a video where an American man says something that sounds like "*you're **boarding***" to warn a woman that her voice is breaking because her connection is bad. What could be the correct word?

https://youtu.be/01vIBIGYF14?t=5175

Comment: It sort of sounds like he said "You're borging." I have no idea what that's supposed to mean.

Comment: Kevin Samuels is an (in my opinion) somewhat dubious YouTube'dating consultant' and 'relationship advisor'). I wonder if 'borging' has some kind of specialised meaning for the kind of person who believes in that kind of stuff.

Comment: @randomhead Thank you. Maybe it's some geek slang then. He's into trading card games and other stuff like that.

Comment: Maybe it's the star trek borg. I think they sort-of speak that way (distorted). see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_etbhWJoMo